# Custom ribbon tab on all pages

Tags: ribbon

I want to create my own Ribbon Tab that will appear on all kinds of pages. What should I do to register this CustomAction? There is not a location setting for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Delegate Control that is attached to the AdditionalPageHead delegate. That custom control can then make sure that your custom Ribbon tab is always visible.

Comment: By accessing the standard ribbon and calling MakeTabAvailable?

Comment: That's the way to go...and you can also use this to make sure that your JavaScript is correctly loaded.

Comment: Thanks Wictor. The custom tab is visible now but as soon as I click on the tab title Loading animation starts inside the tab area and continues forever. Any ideas?

Comment: That's probably an error with your custom ribbon code. You need to open up a new question for that.